# Reliable actors and cancellation token

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

How can my actor instance know that service fabric cluster is being upgraded/stopped so that we can reliably exit? Can we pass along cancellation token from service which invoked the actor? How does this work with reminders?

Answer (score 1):

See if you can prepare for shutdown/upgrade/stop in the Actors' [OnDeactivateAsync](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-lifecycle/) method. This way you don't have to visit a potentially large number of Actors at shutdown.

Alternative:

Actors run inside a special Stateful Service called ActorService. You can create a custom [ActorService](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-platform/) and in its `OnCloseAsync` method you can notify the Actors to do things upon shutdown.
You can find Actors by using [ActorServiceProxy.GetActorsAsync](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-platform/).